# VL_feat functions not visible to parallel workers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vlfeat

So I'm trying to do some image processing using the vl_feat external toolbox, and I'm attempting to run it in parallel, as there's a lot of data to process. So I have a function that includes a parfor loop which calls an accessory function that makes a call to vl_ubcmatch.

Now, when I run my code without first opening a matlabpool, it runs just fine. But, if I open a pool of workers and then run the code, I get an error saying "Undefined function 'vl_ubcmatch' for input arguments of type 'uint8'". So, apparently something in the machinery that sets up the parallel jobs causes it to lose track of the vl_ubcmatch function.

I know that the code for the functions in the vl_feat toolbox isn't in .m files, but rather uses c code and mex files, and I don't fully understand how all that gets bound to function calls, but I'm assuming that something about that implementation confuses the parallel computing toolbox. Has anyone else experienced this, and is there any workaround for it? Thanks in advance.